# Camel pollenrich on mybatis-select looping endlessly

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using a quartz trigger quite sporadically to invoke a mybatis select

```
from( "quartz:'once a minute' )
.pollEnrich( "mybatis://selectItems?statementType=SelectList" )
.process ( ...
```

the select appears correct and runs in a sql-debugger pad correctly. (currently returns no results because table is empty).

When the quartz trigger invokes it starts the poll-enrich, reports no error but just keeps continually re-running the select on the database.
There seems no end it it, it just keeps polling and polling as fast as it can. It never reaches the process point. I have no idea what could be going wrong with it or a way around this problem. Why it is running the select more than once ... it is as though something fails and it comes tries again, but it doesnt give any error message and normally mybatis is very verbose with errors

I have no idea how to fix this...

Here is a dump of just a small section of the logs

```
DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:28,913 [EXEC] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Openning JDBC Connection

DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:28,913 [EXEC] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@X:1234:Y, UserName=A, Oracle JDBC driver]

DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:28,913 [EXEC] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@X:1234:Y, UserName=A, Oracle JDBC driver]

DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:29,428 [EXEC] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Openning JDBC Connection

DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:29,428 [EXEC] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@X:1234:Y, UserName=A, Oracle JDBC driver]

DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:29,428 [EXEC] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@X:1234:Y, UserName=A, Oracle JDBC driver]

DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:29,944 [EXEC] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Openning JDBC Connection

DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:29,944 [EXEC] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@X:1234:Y, UserName=A, Oracle JDBC driver]

DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:29,944 [EXEC] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@X:1234:Y, UserName=A, Oracle JDBC driver]
DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:30,460 [DBIM] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Openning JDBC Connection

DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:30,460 [EXEC] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@X:1234:Y, UserName=A, Oracle JDBC driver]

DEBUG 2013-10-30 14:10:30,460 [EXEC] {Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - mybatis://selectItems} JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@X:1234:Y, UserName=A, Oracle JDBC driver]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use enrich instead of pollEnrich

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It is the answer, he should use enrich instead. And check the Camel's documentation - eg the Content Enricher EIP documentation page which is what he is using to learn this EIP pattern and the difference between the enrich and pollEnrich.